# How do I modify elements in a Perl array inside a foreach loop?

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, foreach

My goal with this piece of code is to sanitize an array of elements (a list of URL's, some with special characters like `%`) so that I can eventually compare it to another file of URL's and output which ones match. The list of URL's is from a `.csv` file with the first field being the URL that I want (with some other entries that I skip over with a quick `if()` statement).

```
foreach my $var(@input_1) {
    #Skip anything that doesn't start with http:
    if ((/^[#U]/ ) || !(/^h/)) {
        next;
    }
    #Split the .csv into the relevant field:
    my @fields = split /\s?\|\s?/, $_;
    $var = uri_unescape($fields[0]);
}
```

My delimiter is a `|` in the csv. In its current setup, and also when I change the `$_` to `$var`, it only returns blank lines. When I remove the `$var` declaration at the beginning of the loop and use `$_`, it will output the URL's in the correct format. But in that case, how can I assign the output to the same element in the array? Would this require a second array to output the value to?

I'm relatively new to perl, so I'm sure there is some stuff that I'm missing. I have no clue at this moment why removing the `$var` at the `foreach` declaration breaks the parsing of the `@fields` line, but removing it and using `$_` doesn't. Reading the [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) documentation did not help as much as I would have liked. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You did not change all the `$_` to `$var`. The `if` condition and the `split` still use `$_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/^h/` is not bound to anything, so the match happens against `$_`. If you want to match `$var`, you have to bind it:

```
if ($var =~ /^[#U]/ || $var !~ /^h/) {
```

Using `||` with two matches could probably be incorporated into a single regular expression with an alternative:

```
next if $var =~ /^(?: [#U] | [^h] | $ )/x;
```

i.e. The line has to start with `#`, `U`, something else than `h`, or be empty.

You can populate a new array with the results by using `push`:

```
push @results, $var;
```

Also note that if your data can contain `|` quoted or escaped (or newlines etc.), you should use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) instead of `split`.

Comment: I would use Text::CSV regardless if the current data has a '|' character in it. There are enough edge-cases in a 'simple' format like CSV to not write your own parser for it in anything but the most trivial cases.

Comment: Thank you. The editing the if field fixed it. I didn't even think to look into the if construction. I'll look into Text::CSV, it sound like something I'll be using a lot of.